# Converting String to byte from XML file

Tags: java, android, xml

I am having struggles to finish my code. I am parsing an XML, which returns to me `String` values (using `xpp.getAttributeValue(0);`). However, in my actual code, I need `byte` and not a `String`.

A simple conversion is `Byte.valueOf(String);` however, the returned value is not correct!

**XML example:**

```
<userId value="0xAA"></userId>
```

When I parse this with:

```
String stringUserId = xpp.getAttributeValue(0);
```

and then convert it to bytes with:

```
byte byteUserId = Byte.valueOf(stirngUserId);
```

**I do not get 0xAA value.** Can someone please help me?

Comment: What value do you get? Keep in mind that `byte` is signed, so `0xAA` is a negative number.

Comment: @Thilo Sorry, forgot to write it down and now Im not next to PC anymore. But it definetly wasn't 0xAA!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String stringUserId = xpp.getAttributeValue(0);
byte byteUserId[] = stringUserId.getBytes() ;
```

Actually `String` is a array of `bytes`.

Comment: That will give you four bytes with the ASCII encoded values of '0', 'x', 'A', 'A'.  Probably not what AndroidDev101 wants.

Comment: That is a bit pattern

Comment: I would like to avoid converting each ASCII. I just want to get 0xAA, but in byte format not in String as it is by default using XmlPullParser.

Thanks for suggestion, will test it anyway as soon as I get back to PC.

Comment: @Thilo   Hi guys, so I tried this and it did not work. I need either int as 0xAA or byte as 0xAA. With XML I get String="0xAA". And I don't know how to convert it to simple remove the "" and save it as int or byte (not byte array).

Answer (score 0):

`Byte.valueOf(string)` doesn't return a native `byte` type, it returns `Byte`. Try to do something like this:

```
Byte byteobj = Byte.valueOf(stirngUserId);
byte byteUserId = byteobj.byteValue();
```

Comment: Thanks, will test it as soon as I can, if it works, I accept the answer.

Comment: Hi Daniel, unfortunately, this did not do the trick for me.
Do you have any other suggestion? I just want to remove from String the "", so that I get only 0xAA and save it as byte or int (not byte array).

Comment: It keeps saying "invalid int: 0xAA"

Answer (score 0):

Try [Integer#decode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29). It should understand the "0x" syntax.

```
int x = Integer.decode(stringUserId);
```